# R: Summary of SQL Tables

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi

I am working with the R programming language.

Normally, when I want to get the summary of a table, I can use something like the "`str()`" function or the `"summary()"` function:

```
str(my_table)

summary(my_table)
```

However, now I am trying to do this with tables on a server.

For instance, I am trying to get the summaries of variable types for a specific table (e.g. "my_table") on a server. I found a very indirect way to do this:

```
#load libraries
library(OBDC)
library(RODBC)
library(dbi)

#establish a connection and name it as "dbhandle"

rs <- dbSendQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from my_table limit 1')

dbColumnInfo(rs)
```

**My Question:** Is there a more "direct" way to do this? For example, can I get information  about each column (e.g. whether the column is integer, character, date, etc.) in a table without first sending the query and then requesting the information? Can I do this directly?

Thanks!

Comment: In MySQL there is a `describe` statement, in postgresql there is another way to get the information, please check  https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/. I'm not sure what you mean by `Can I do this directly?` when you are invoking databases/tables from R.

Comment: Many DBMSes have a pseudo table `information_schema.columns`, where you can do something like: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='my_table'`. (Caveats: `select *` is considered sloppy by some, ymmv; some DBMSes like mssql implement this but encourage something proprietary for whatever reason.)

Comment: @r2evans: thank you for your reply! I tried your code: dbGetQuery(dbhandle, "select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'my_table' ")

Comment: This gives me a list of 50 options: [1] TABLE_CATALOG [2] TABLE_SCHEMA [3] TABLE_NAME [4] COLUMN_NAME ...Etc

Comment: Is there a way to open one of these? Thank you so much!

Comment: stats555, that frame should have one row for each column of `my_table`. Look at them, they have lots of information (and a lot of nulls too, by-design). I find a quick-look of `str(..)` on that returned frame to be useful. Or `View(.)` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `fetch()` from "RMySQL" to turn your SQL query into an R object (e.g. data frame)

```
library(RMySQL)
rs <- dbSendQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from my_table limit 1')
# Get the results from MySQL into R
my_table = fetch(rs, n=-1)
# clear result
dbClearResult(rs)
rm(rs)
```

Then use the functions you describe.

```
str(my_table)

summary(my_table)
```

Comment: @ Dustin: thank you for your answer! "My_table" is too big to fit on to the local computer. Will the code you have provided run on the server? Thank you so much!

Comment: The "fetch" command returns an error:  error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'fetch' for signature "OdbcResult", "numeric"

Comment: Do you know what might be causing this error? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can't use `RMySQL::fetch` on an `odbc::odbc()` connection, why should that work? `DBI::dbFetch` (and `DBI::fetch`, if you really want to use it, though `dbFetch` is preferred) and `odbc::dbFetch` exist, I see no reason why `RMySQL` was brought into the fray.

Comment: Really, just `dbGetQuery(dbhandle, 'select ... limit 1')` should work by itself. @stats555, you say `My_table is too big`, but this query explicitly loads just one row (`limit 1`), does the table really have a lot of columns, or are you just learning about the `LIMIT` clause? (BTW: that works in most but not all DBMSes; if on SQL Server, change that to `select top 1 * from my_table`.)